# solidity get ParserError: need correct code

Tags: solidity

```
    contract Base {
    uint256 Age;
    function getAge(uint256 Age) public{ 
        x = Age;
        return x;
    }
    function sumAge(uint256 y) internal pure (uint256){
        uint256 newAge = x + y;
        return newAge;
    }
}
```

Expected '{' but got '(' function sumAge(uint256 y) internal pure..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `returns` expression.

```
function sumAge(uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256) {
```

Comment: Hi，after I added the returns expression, I got DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier newAge, can you also please give some suggestions on how to make it work. Thanks!         Here is the error comes:  uint256 newAge = x + y;
        return newAge;

Comment: I'm getting "Undeclared identifier" for `x`, not for `newAge`. It's because the `x` is not available in this scope. You need to define it as the contract property.

Comment: I have change the code as below, can you help fix it, thanks! contract Base {
    uint256 Age;
    function getAge(uint256 x) public{ 
        Age = x;
        return Age;
    }
    function sumAge(uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256){
        uint256 newAge = x + b;
        return newAge;
    }
}